# Detect place/location name in a given string

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I'm a PHP developer and I'm looking to implement a search feature on my application that incorporates a keyword search as well as a location search, for example:

"Plumbers in York", "Electricians in Birmingham" or "Gardeners in NE63"

So, the anatomy of a search string is:

```
"Electricians in Birmingham"
 |__________|    |________|
       |              |
    Keywords      Location
```

What I basically need to do is extract the keywords and the location, where location could be a place name or partial postcode.

The questions I have is how do I actually know which string is the location (given that the stop word, "in" could be missing).

Is there a place name detection library as a part of the Google maps API that I can leverage?

My technology stack that I'm planning on using is:

- PHP
- Elastic Search
- Google Maps API

Comment: Let's assume a search like "[pilot](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dpilot)  [carpenter](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dcarpenter)" , both words may be a location or a keyword, how would you distinguish between them?

Comment: Could you not create 2 separate inputs? One for the keyword, one for the location, then merge both in your request?

Answer (score 1):

I probably am too late to the party but wanted to give my two cents on this.
I came across this problem recently while trying to implement a search for my platform. I used google geocoding API (detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_342710847024-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7E%20Geocoding%20API%20BMM-KWID_43700042841957294-kwd-301485308042-userloc_1007768&utm_term=KW_%2Bgeocoding%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bgeocoding%20%2Bapi&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuLOtpp6a6gIVSyUrCh2ONAzCEAAYASAAEgJEVfD_BwE)) to achieve the same thing.

Pros :

1. You can supply any search string containing a location and it gives the locations for you

Cons :

1. Adversely affects the search speed : in worst case , I have seen it take about a second to respond adding to the search time ( I am actually planning to move away from this for this very reason)
2. It sometimes detects location even when there are none , leading to wrong results

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Code Point Open](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/beginner-s-guide/postal/index.html) or [Open Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html) from Ordnance Survey to create a list of postcodes, cities, towns, villages, counties in the UK. Then look for phrases from that list within your search string.

However be warned that there are over [3,000 postcode districts](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/beginner-s-guide/postal/index.html) (the first portion) and over 1.75 million full postcodes, then there are several thousand settlements which are not unique (St Neots, Denton, Hatfield) and some town names are also a bit ambiguous (March, Battle, Fleet) and not obviously proper nouns.

If you have a powerful search tech you could do this of course. However it's probably simpler to adjust the UI to include a separate field for location, either postcode with radius based or a hierarchy of regions to counties to towns etc.